# NumberFormat: Is there a way to GET the separator?

Tags: php

**different countries different separators for the decimal point and thousands separators**.

the input of a value could be, for example,
1120,00
1120.00
1,120.00
1.120,00

with the **NumberFormat** (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) you can set a separator but how can I get a separator depending of the NumberFormat (which can be, e.g., set/extracted from the **browser language**)?

Do I have to do it manually in **PHP**?

Comment: You can read the current locale settings using [localeconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php), using [setlocale()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) will allow you to specify which locale settings you want to check

Comment: that's it :) tnx a lot